# Spring boot not complaining about two beans with the same name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm having the following configuration where I have two Spring beans with the same name from two different configuration classes.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

---

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Configuration 
public class OtherRestTemplateConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

And I am injecting (and using) this bean like this:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Component
public class SomeComponent {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

}
```

Now, my question is: why is Spring not complaining about having multiple beans with the same name?  I would expect an exception here and having to add a `@Primary` annotation to make sure that the correct one is being used.

On a side note: even if I add `@Primary` it is still not always injecting the correct one.

Comment: You cannot have beans with the same name, the end result will be a single bean as one bean overrides the other, due to the same name. Hence there is only a single bean in the context. To get multiple beans give them different names and annotate one with `@Primary`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the beans is overriding other one because you use same name. If different names were used as @paweł-głowacz suggested, then in case of using

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate myRestTemplate;
```

spring will complain because it finds two beans with same RestTemplate type and doesnt know which to use. Then you apply `@Primary` to one of them.

More explanation here: [more info](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10795?focusedCommentId=113426&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-113426)

Comment: I am already injecting the bean by name and spring does not complain.  Updated the question.

Comment: its not complaining because 1st one is overriden by 2nd, because same name is used:) take a look into logs, you should find message beginning with `Overriding bean definition for bean 'restTemplate'`

Comment: Ok, so one of them gets overriden.  But even if I add `@Primary` to the correct one, it's still not taking that one.  (That's what I was trying in the first place).  The overriding log part even mentions replacing `... primary=true...` with `... primary=false ...`

Comment: did you change names for both of them and annotate @Primary one of them?

Comment: No I didn't, and that seems to be the part I was missing.  I thought it was not necessary when using `@Primary`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to name that beans so:

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfiguration {

    @Bean(name="bean1")
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

And

```
@Configuration 
public class OtherRestTemplateConfiguration {

    @Bean(name="bean2")
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to differentiate between the two.  I would like to annotate the one I'd like to use with `@Primary` , but my question is why it is not clashing without the annotation.

Comment: When you mark with `@Bean` you tell spring that: `Hey fellow, you are going to manage that objects`. So spring creates proxies for that objects. Under spring management with annotation `@Bean` spring need to have unique Beans. In above example to make that happens you have to mark beans with unique names to resolve conflict that spring call. Without annotation `@Bean` spring wont know nothing about that beans and there will be no errors

Comment: Yes, I do understand that, but why is it not complaining when they have the same name?

Comment: When there is no `@Bean` annotation or what?

Comment: No there is a `@Bean` annotation without a name specified.  So I'd expect spring to create these beans with the name of the method.  Which is the same in botch cases.

Comment: You are using the same method name so this is equivalent to this: `<bean name="restTemplate" class="your.package.OtherRestTemplateConfiguration "/>` and `<bean name="restTemplate" class="your.package.RestTemplateConfiguration "/>`. See there is the conflict. If you want different name you have two options: Annotate with `@Bean(name="bean_name")` or change method name in one of your Configuration classes.

Comment: there is no conflict, one of them is overriden. He wants them to conflict, and resolve it using @Primary