# @Configuration & @Bean multiple which can be inject

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

this is a springBoot1.5.22 project.I have 3 java config Bean ,use `@Configuration` and `@Bean` annotation.
when i try to run project with debug mode。why `myBean` method of `ConfigurationC` execute ？ ，the `myBean` method of `ConfigurationA` and `ConfigurationB` not execute。what is mechanism ?
[packages of the classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qM3dp.png)
[start class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79YOs.png)

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationA {
    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean(){
        System.out.println("ConfigurationA myBean init");
        return new MyBean();
    }
}

@Configuration
public class ConfigurationB {
    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean(){
        System.out.println("ConfigurationB myBean init");
        return new MyBean();
    }
}

@Configuration
public class ConfigurationC {
    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean(){
        System.out.println("ConfigurationC myBean init");
        return new MyBean();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to run these? How are these three classes being included into other code so they will run?

Comment: Without knowing the packages of the classes and how you bootstrap the application this is impossible to answer. Please provide a minimal and reproducible sample instead of just snippets of code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004196/spring-boot-not-complaining-about-two-beans-with-the-same-name Given that your three beans share the same name, this might help...

Comment: They all define beans of exactly the same name. You are getting log messages that indicate that the definition of `myBean` is being replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @jackycflau said in the comment above, all your beans have the same name.

These three beans, all with the same name and type, are being loaded (*but not yet initialized*) sequentially into the application context (bean container). When a bean named "myBean" of type `MyBean` is returned from the application context, you get the one from `ConfigurationC` because it was the last one written into the container, which overwrote the previous two beans of the same name/type. It's apparently not being initialized until it's actually pulled from the container by client code, which is why it's the only one whose code actually runs.

Comment: all method can be execute in this way，My question is they have same name of method，why myBean of ConfigurationC can execute，why not ConfigurationA or ConfigurationB？

Comment: I would presume that it's because the Spring application context (bean container) is loading all three of those bean definitions. ConfigurationA#myBean is loaded first and then overwritten when ConfigurationB#myBean is loaded. That is then finally overwritten when ConfigurationC#myBean loads next. Since this is the last one standing, it runs when "myBean" is pulled from the container. It's an educated guess, but I think it's probably basically correct.

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck to you!

Answer (score 0):

please provide code snippets to analyse it more.

Bean id should be unique. I don't think you would be allowed to create beans with same beanid.

please try below code

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationA {
    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean(){
        System.out.println("ConfigurationA myBean init");
        return new MyBean();
    }
}

@Configuration
public class ConfigurationB {
    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean1(){
        System.out.println("ConfigurationB myBean init");
        return new MyBean();
    }
}

@Configuration
public class ConfigurationC {
    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean2(){
        System.out.println("ConfigurationC myBean init");
        return new MyBean();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Boot 1.5.x the bean overriding is enabled by default.

This means, the bean definition tree is built first and then the last overriding bean is used (executed), all others are ignored (as they were overrided). In your case the last definition comes from `ConfigurationC`.

This mechanism prevents from ambitious bean definitions, where more than one definition is found, and Spring can't know which one to use - an error occurs (`BeanDefinitionOverrideException`).

Please note, this must be explicit enabled in [Spring Boot 2.x](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes#bean-overriding).

Answer (score 0):

You can try specifying names:

```
@Bean(name="bean1")
```

and then select the injected bean:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("bean1")
```